# How to create white css box shadow

Tags: css, shadow

I have the following box shadow css on my site. It looks great in Chrome, but Firefox and IE do not recreate the effect I'm looking for. I want a white solid shadow only on the bottom of a box. How do I make this work for all browsers?

```
box-shadow: 0px 10px -14px 14px #FFF;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px -14px 14px #FFF;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px -14px 14px rgb(255, 255, 255);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this [article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/) or this code:

```
 -moz-box-shadow: 13px 13px 0px 0px #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 13px 13px 0px 0px #FFFFFF;
     box-shadow: 13px 13px 0px 0px  #FFFFFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working in IE9 and FF by simply removing the vendor prefix lines. All you should need is:

```
box-shadow: 0px 10px -14px 14px #FFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a negative value for the shadow size:

```
box-shadow: 0px 10px -14px 14px #FFF;
```

A negative `14px` shadow would be nothing, as it would be less than it having a size of 0. If you're looking for an `inset` shadow, simply add that to the style:

```
box-shadow: inset...
```

Solution, change `-14px` to `14px`.